# CSS Button has white margin/padding that cannot be removed

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page that someone long ago created. One of the things they didn't care about much was the finished button design for one of the buttons on this page. I'm back in this program/page, and decided I'd try to make it look better, and for the life of me I cannot fix this issue.

Here is a fiddle of the button: http://jsfiddle.net/h5CkS/

The white space, no matter what I do, will not go away. I have not been able to find a way to fill it, "paint" over it with the span/div, or anything. If I try to tweak an element to be wider, or fill up the padding, it just restacks the "New" under "Unvet".

I cannot simply fill this button with an image, because of some creative javascript that targets on the button-span-div combo formed.

So I have to somehow tackle this with the CSS. Is there anything that anyone can think of how I can be rid of that damned whitespace?

Thanks.

EDIT: Just to show how frustrating this is. I played with the Fiddle and made this:http://jsfiddle.net/h5CkS/6/ which looks perfect. But when I put that into the page code, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WihUt.jpg.

Comment: If it can help you, here's a rock-solid reset for `button`: http://fvsch.com/code/button-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fork of your Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GXU4w/8/ Changes are:

1) Negative margin on spans

2) border-width: 1px on button

Comment: This has gotten me somewhat closer. The blue area moved over a bit. The problem is, it affects another button that uses that same CSS class. So I might just make a separate one just for this button. Thanks so much, and I'll post final solution once it's been found.

Comment: Sure, no problem. But please test in several browsers as those negative margins are quite tricky to adjust.

Comment: So using this method, finally came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h5CkS/16/) code. It is borked in Fiddle, but looks good in FF. However, you were correct, and it looks bad in IE. I showed my boss, and the final decision is to simply create a background image, and change the javascript so it doesn't care about the spans anymore. (Original Coder had a great idea at the time, it was just visually horrible. With the amount of work to make it look nice for one button is overkill.)

Answer (score 0):

- Set the `border-width` property on `.arrow` to `9px 14px`.
- Set the `font-size` property on `.arrow-button` to `0`.
- Set the `width` property on `.arrow-button span` to `84px`.
- Set the `font-size` property on `.arrow-button span` to `12px` or whatever seems reasonable.

Comment: Those changes give roughly the same result as what I responded to DRP96 below with.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of `.arrow-button span` to `83px` and add `height: 14px;`.

Comment: if also margin: and padding for these elements are 0 it works (i tested it yesterday)